# How find this sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}\cdot 2^{m-i}$

Tags: number-theory

> let $n$ is give odd positive integer numbers, and postive integer $m$  such
>    $$2^m\equiv 1\pmod n
> ,2^i\equiv a_{i}\pmod n,0\le a_{i}\le n-1,a_{i}\neq 1,i=1,2,\cdots,m-1$$
>   Find the sum
>   $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}\cdot 2^{m-i}$$

follow is  my idea: let 
$$n=2k+1,k\in N^{+}$$
then we have
$$2^m\equiv 1\pmod n$$
use Euler's theorem,we have
$$m=\phi{(n)}=\phi{(2k+1)}$$
then I can't Continue,Thank you

I fell @Ivan Loh and so on can kill it.can you help me? because this problem I have consider a One night,and I fell maybe you can't understand my problem?

This problem is from china 2013 a maths examination, but the official did not give the solution,

Comment: You might want to join forces with user @math110. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/815686

Comment: Euler's theorem doesn't say $m = \phi(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Final answer is $1$ for $n=1$, and for $n>1$ we have $$\frac{(2^m-1)(n-2)}{n}$$ Proof below.

---

$n=1$ straightforward. Henceforth consider $n>1$.

Write $kn=2^m-1$ and expand $k$ in binary as $k=\epsilon_02^0+\epsilon_12^1+ \ldots \epsilon_{m-1}2^{m-1}$, each $\epsilon_i$  being $0$ or $1$.

Note that $$\left\lfloor \frac{k+\frac{1}{2}}{2^i} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2^i} \right\rfloor=\sum_{j=i}^{m-1}{\epsilon_j 2^{j-i}} \equiv \epsilon_i \pmod{2}$$

---

**Claim:** $a_{m-i} \equiv \epsilon_i \pmod{2}$ for $0 \leq i \leq m-1$.

Indeed, consider $2^{m-i}=\alpha n+a_{m-i}$, where $0 \leq a_{m-i} \leq n-1$, so that $$\alpha=\left\lfloor \frac{2^{m-i}}{n}\right\rfloor$$

We have $kn+1=2^m=2^i(2^{m-i})$ so $$\frac{2^{m-i}}{n}=\frac{kn+1}{n2^i}=\frac{k}{2^i}+\frac{1}{n2^i}$$
$$\frac{k}{2^i} \leq \frac{k}{2^i}+\frac{1}{n2^i} \leq \frac{k}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2(2^i)}=\frac{k+\frac{1}{2}}{2^i}$$

Thus $$\alpha=\left\lfloor \frac{2^{m-i}}{n}\right\rfloor=\left \lfloor \frac{k}{2^i}+\frac{1}{n2^i} \right \rfloor\sum_{j=i}^{m-1}{\epsilon_j 2^{j-i}} \equiv \epsilon_i \pmod{2}$$

Then $$a_{m-i}=2^{m-i}-\alpha n \equiv 0-\alpha \equiv \alpha \equiv \epsilon_i \pmod{2}$$
(Note $n$ odd. Also $2 \mid 2^{m-i}$ since $0 \leq i \leq m-1$)

---

Now we have

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^{m}{(-1)^{a_i}2^{m-i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^{a_{m-i}}2^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^{\epsilon_i}2^i}$$

Note since $\epsilon_i$ is $0$ or $1$, $(-1)^{\epsilon_i}=1-2\epsilon_i$. Thus

\begin{align}
S=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{(-1)^{\epsilon_i}2^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{(1-2\epsilon_i)2^i}& =\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{2^i}-2\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}{\epsilon_i2^i}\\
&=2^m-1-2k\\
&=2^m-1-2\frac{2^m-1}{n}\\
&=\frac{(2^m-1)(n-2)}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: It's Nice! Thank you +1