# How find this sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}\cdot 2^{m-i}$ and $2^i\equiv a_{i}\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, summation

**Question:**

> let $n$ is give odd positive integer numbers,and $a_{i}\neq 1,0\le a_{i}\le n-1$,
> and $$2^i\equiv a_{i}\pmod n,i=1,2,\cdots,m-1$$
>
> where $m(m\le n)$ such $2^m\equiv 1\pmod n$
>
> Find the sum
> $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}\cdot 2^{m-i}$$

My try: since
$$2^m\equiv 1\pmod n\Longrightarrow m=\phi{(n)}$$

and for example

when $n=3$, it is clear $m=2$,so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}2^{m-i}=(-1)^2\cdot 2^{2-1}+(-1)^1\cdot 2^{2-2}=2-1=1$$

when
$n=5$, it is clear $m=4$,so
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}2^{m-i}=(-1)^2\cdots 2^{4-1}+(-1)^4\cdot 2^{4-2}+(-1)^3\cdot 2^{4-3}+(-1)^1\cdot 2^{4-4}=8+4-2-1=9$$

when
$n=7$,It is clear $m=3$,then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}(-1)^{a_{i}}\cdot 2^{m-i}=(-1)^2\cdot 2^{3-1}+(-1)^4\cdot 2^{3-2}+(-1)^1\cdot 2^{3-3}=4+2-1=5$$

and so on

**But for general
,I can't.This problem  is from   a competition in china 2013**

Thank you for you help.

Comment: You might want to join forces with user @chinamath. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/815637/

Comment: Oh,I think my idea maybe is usefull

Comment: @Did hmm, since I've answered the other one (I saw that first), we should perhaps close this as a duplicate.